# Specify exact path of program to be opened via .bat file

Tags: batch-file

- I want to open Autodesk Civil3D Metric with a batch file.
- I can only get it to run the generic AutoCAD via a batch file.

Upon looking at the file path, it seems there may be an extra step in opening the Civil3D Metric tools build on the normal CAD platform (at least this is my line of thought).

From Explorer when opening the shortcut properties (see screenshot also )

**Start in:** "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\UserDataCache"

**Target:** "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\acad.exe" /ld "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\AecBase.dbx" /p "<<C3D_Metric>>"  /product "C3D" /language "en-US"

Is there a way to open the complete suite via batch?

Best regards,
J

[explorer properties of program to be opened via .bat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtBud.png)

Comment: What about `@start "" /D "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\UserDataCache" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\acad.exe" /ld "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\AecBase.dbx" /p "<<C3D_Metric>>" /product "C3D" /language "en-US"`? This is exactly the same as double clicking on the shortcut file as it results also in running the Windows kernel function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the same parameters by `cmd.exe` as it is done by `explorer.exe` on double clicking on the shortcut file.